# How to perform each iteration of a for loop at a button click

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a for loop. I would like to perform each iteration of the for loop only after a button is pressed.
Please I need an idea.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: That is actually the problem. I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: At least show what the loop would look like and what would trigger the button. Hint: you also need to store a state somewhere, to know at which iteration of the loop you are.

Comment: It is a for loop. According to the value of the loop counter I know at which iteration the loop is at any moment. What I want is to stop the loop from incrementing the loop counter until I press a button. Only when the button_Click event handler is called, then must the loop counter be increased.

Comment: Try to solve an easier problem: Show somewhere the number of times the button is pressed. If you solved that problem, your problem becomes easier to solve.

Comment: I am sorry, but your simpler problem is not clear to me. In order to know how many times a button was pressed, a global variable must be declared and incremented in the button_Click event handler.

Comment: Yes correct, so instead of a for-loop you can write something that uses your global variable.